# Populate dynamic checkbox with dynamic values codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, dynamic, checkbox

I have a form with add and edit function. Inside the form, they have checkboxes. The checkboxes itself is generated from mysql table.

When I want to do add function, the checkbox are populated correctly. However, I have issue when I entering edit function of the form.

I need the checkbox values are checked based when I do submit.

Here is my code:

**Controller:**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $data['query'] = $this->Campaign_model->edit($id);
    $data['branch_list'] = $this->Campaign_model->get_branch_list();
    $data['branch_checked'] = $this->Campaign_model->get_checked_branches($id);

    $this->load->view('campaign_form', $data);
}
```

The `$data['branch_list']` contains the primary checkboxes. The `$data['branch_checked']` contains which checkboxes are checked within current data (query).

**View:**

```
$branch_id = "";

foreach($branch_list as $branch_list_checkbox)
{
    if($branch_list_checkbox->id == $branch_checked->branch_id)
    {
        $branch_id .= '<label><input name="branch_id[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$branch_list_checkbox->id.'" checked />'.$branch_list_checkbox->name.'</label>&nbsp;';
    }
    else
    {
        $branch_id .= '<label><input name="branch_id[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$branch_list_checkbox->id.'" />'.$branch_list_checkbox->name.'</label>&nbsp;';
    }           
}
```

Everything in `$branch_list` are populated properly. But how do I assign the `$branch_checked` properly to their respective checkboxes?

Need help, thanks.

Comment: There has to be a way to better optimize your queries, and to include the checked status into the branch list.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like you are doing it correctly.  Maybe instead of just putting "checked" you need to put

```
$branch_id .= '<label><input name="branch_id[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$branch_list_checkbox->id.'" checked="checked" />'.$branch_list_checkbox->name.'</label>&nbsp;';
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually only `checked` is fine. When I run code above, it produces error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/campaign_form.php

Line Number: 104
```

Line 104 is :

```
if($branch_list_checkbox->id == $branch_checked->branch_id)
```

And there is 2 boxes of the error.

The output produced by `$branch_list` and `$branch_checked` are arrays so I think I supposed to do a `foreach` to `$branch_checked` but I dunno how to write it.

I googling and found `foreach($a as $b => $c)` but I dont understand how it works; however I tried to put any variables possibly used on the code and it produces error.